# How to update only new data in Chart.JS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, chart.js

Actually after pressing a button in my website i call a bootstrap modal inside which there is a Chart.JS the data for that Chart are load from an Ajax call in the following way

```
function loadReports(data) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "Default.aspx/getReports",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        data: JSON.stringify({ data: data }),
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (r) {
            data = r.d;
            if (data != '[]') {
                data = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
                var dataObject = {
                    labels: data.map(ora => ora.ORARIO),
                    datasets: [{
                        label: 'Coperti',
                        backgroundColor: gradient,
                        hoverBackgroundColor: gradient,
                        data: data.map(cop => cop.COPERTI)
                    }]          
                };
                chart.data = dataObject;
                chart.update(0);
            } else {
                var dataObject = {
                    labels: [],
                    datasets: []
                }
                chart.data = dataObject;
                chart.update();
            }

        },
        error: function (error) {
            alert(error.responseText);
        }
    });

}
```

Now i would to "*live update*" that chart but the issue obviously is that by doing an `ajax poll` of that function **all the chart data are updated**

While i would to update **only the new data** so if i have a chart build as `labels ["15:00","16:00"]` `datasets [5,8]` when a new data has been added to database as *17:00 / 9* i would to add only the new value or another example if the data of 15:00 has changed to 10 i would to update only the value set in label 15:00.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can update both things

1. New label with new data point
2. update exisiting datapoint

   ```
   document.getElementById('addData').addEventListener('click', function() {
           if (config.data.datasets.length > 0) {
               var month = MONTHS[config.data.labels.length % MONTHS.length];
               config.data.labels.push(month);

               config.data.datasets.forEach(function(dataset) {
                   dataset.data.push(randomScalingFactor());
               });

               window.myLine.update();
           }
       });
               document.getElementById('updateOnlyPoint').addEventListener('click', function() {
           if (config.data.datasets.length > 0) {
               var month = config.data.labels.indexOf("March");//change point
               var olddata=config.data.datasets[0].data
                olddata[month]=randomScalingFactor(); //new data
               window.myLine.update();
           }
       });
   ```

here is working [example](https://jsfiddle.net/Negirox/tr1640u5/)